# how to find records between two string dates SQLITE - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

```
 String start = "9-4-2015";
 String end = "11-4-2015";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
 List<IncomeModel> allToDos = db.getAllIncomesWeeks();

 for (IncomeModel todo : allToDos) {
    DatabaseDate = todo.getDate();
    try {
          if (sdf.parse(start).before(sdf.parse(end))) {
               incomeModel.add(todo);
               sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(todo.getAmount());
              }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  tvSum.setText(sum + "");
```

I need a record between start date and end date.
I also Tried This Query

```
"SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE date BETWEEN '"+ start + "' AND '" + end + "'"
```

But It's Also Shows Wrong Data.

Comment: Your date must be as `09-04-2015` then only it works.

Comment: this question is for android specially so i think it is not duplicate...

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer. So you can accept it, in order to remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format must be `2015-04-09`, to work.
For your reference: http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html